# Vector values becoming NaN

Tags: c++

I keep getting nan (not a number) as a result for the various floats and vector components throughout my program. I am almost 100% certain is has to do with collision because this was never an issue before I messed with the collision code.

Even the sum in the magnitude method is showing up as NaN when I debug it, which leads me to believe a vector is breaking before being passed into the function, but I cannot find which one it is.

Here are the methods that I believe are relevant to the problem

```
void Simplex::PhysicsInfo::Collision(PhysicsInfo info)
{
    vector3 oldVel = velocity;
    if (magnitude(oldVel) == 0.0f)
    {
        return;
    }
    vector3 nextVelDirect = glm::normalize(info.position - position);

//make all ball to ball collisions elastic

    float angle = acosf(glm::dot(oldVel, nextVelDirect)
            / (magnitude(glm::normalize(oldVel)) * magnitude(nextVelDirect)));
    angle = sinf(angle);
    if (angle < 0)
        angle *= -1;
    float nextVecMag;
    if (magnitude(info.velocity) == 0 && angle != 1)
    {
        //This next line is not correct, use if actual line isn't working and you absolutely need something
        //info.velocity = 0.5f * oldVel.length * nextVelDirect;

        //actual line
        info.velocity = angle * magnitude(oldVel) * nextVelDirect;
        vector3 nextVec = (magnitude(oldVel) * oldVel)
                - (magnitude(info.velocity) * info.velocity);
        nextVecMag = magnitude(nextVec);
        if (nextVecMag < 0)
        {
            nextVecMag *= -1;
        }
        nextVecMag = sqrt(nextVecMag);
        velocity = nextVecMag * glm::normalize(nextVec);
    }
    else if (magnitude(info.velocity) == 0)
    {
        info.velocity = oldVel;
        velocity = vector3(0.0f);
    }
    if (isnan(velocity.x) || isnan(velocity.y) || isnan(velocity.z))
    {
        std::cout << "-" << std::endl;
    }
}

PhysicsInfo::PhysicsInfo(float mss, vector3 pos, vector3 cent, vector3 limit)
{
    velocity = vector3(0.1f);
    acceleration = vector3(0.0f);
    mass = mss;
    position = pos;
    center = cent;
    limits = limit;
    frictionMagnitude = 0.005f;
}
vector3 PhysicsInfo::normalize(const vector3 &v)
{
    float sum = (v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z);
    if (sum < 0)
    {
        sum *= -1;
    }
    float length_of_v = sqrt(sum);
    return vector3(v.x / length_of_v, v.y / length_of_v, v.z / length_of_v);
}

float PhysicsInfo::magnitude(const vector3 &v)
{
    float sum = (v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z);
    if (sum < 0)
    {
        sum *= -1;
    }
    float length_of_v = sqrt(sum);
    if (isnan(length_of_v))
    {
        throw ExceptionCollidedUnwind;
    }
    return length_of_v;
}
```

Sorry for the formatting. I am not used to posting here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use a debugger to step through your code and to figure out where exactly the `NaN` comes from. That is much easier than trying to guess from a code snippet without context.

Comment: The big problem with providing code snippets, as opposed to an [mcve], is if you don't know what the problem is, how can you know where it is?

Comment: Just sprinkle more assert() calls through this code, where ever you do something that is risky.  Big bummer if length_of_v is 0 for example, so you want to check that.  And don't hide bugs, something Really Bad happened when magnitude() is less than 0.  You probably already discovered something was fishy before to flip the sign like that, don't ignore the smelly fish.  Test with very small varied datasets so you can find data-induced bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I have not fixed the issue yet, but I have deciphered that the cause was the parameter to the acosf() function located the the Collision method. The dot method sometimes returns outside of the required range of [-1, 1], the required range of floats for the parameter to the acosf() method. This was caused because I did not normalize both vectors before getting the dot product.